# How to use the value returned from a firebase function outside its scope?

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, scope

I have this function:

```
let userDisplayName;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
  if (user){
    userDisplayName = user;
  }
  else {
    console.log('error');
  }
  this.setState ({user: userDisplayName})
  return userDisplayName;
})
console.log(userDisplayName, 'udn');
```

`userDisplayName` is giving me the correct value however, only in the scope of the function. When I `console.log` I am told that the value is undefined and when I try to `setState` I get told I cant use that function inside there (doesn't know what `this` is). How can I return the variable so that it has the value I'm expecting outside the scope so that I can set state with it?

Comment: Putting the call outside of the callback means that it does not wait for anything, which you always need to do with asynchronous methods. Notice that `return userDisplayName;` does not work either in a non-promise callback

Comment: and you need to bind `this` https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: @Bergi so how can I resolve the async stuff? What would the promise look like?

Comment: Afaik firebase already provides a promise-based API, try searching for that